# Java - Why am I unable to click generate javadoc button on netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

Im trying to generate a javadoc for the project I have created by right clicking the project on the navigator on the left. I see the option, but it wont let me click the button "Generate Javadoc" in net beans.

Could someone please tell me whats causing this problem and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `Generate JavaDoc` Button does not actually generate any JavaDocs. You need to write the docs yourself.

But once you have all the docs in your code, you can click that button and it will generate you a list of nicely formatted HTML pages and put them into your target (dist) directory

This is what you need to have a complete JavaDoc for a method:

```
 /** 
 * This is a JavaDoc example for an example Method
 *
 * @param someParameter here an explanation what this parameter stands for
 * @return the String value of the parameter
 */
 public String exampleMethod(int someParameter){
      // just a useless example
      return ""+someParameter;
 }
```

You need `@param <name of the parameter>` for each parameter in your method signature and *if* the method returns something you need the `@return` tag. Even if everyone sees what type this method returns, it is good practice to mention it again in a short sentence.

If you have that you will no longer get any warnings. And maybe (when there are no more warnings) NetBeans will let you generate the html pages with that button.

Comment: Yea i have already written the comments. But i get this warming "warning: no @param for" for certain methods. What does this mean?